# Does foursquare provide any test accounts for developers?

Tags: foursquare

Does foursquare provide any test accounts for developers?

For example: I want to test a special through api. I need a venue for creating a special. Does Foursquare provide us ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no. Either find a venue manager who can authorize you application, or e-mail api@foursquare.com for help setting up a "fake" venue for you to claim.